# 2HOT Thermometer "in flight above 7,300 meters" at Minmus?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I have been given a mission to "Measure the temperature in flight above 7,300 meters near Gene's Deposit". I flew to Gene's Deposit on Minmus, put myself on a suborbital trajectory, and attempted to Log Temperature somewhere between 8000-9000m ASL. The game responded "Temperature scan can't be done right now."

How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're still too high for the thermometre to register a temperature. Get right down to barely above 7,300m and take the reading there.

Comment: Wow, that's a tiny margin. Contract complete, thanks!